# using matplotlib from ipython session in emacs on windows

Tags: windows, matplotlib, emacs, ipython, elpy

*** Update: the problem is with running python inside emacs on windows.  ipython and elpy are off the hook.  From a plain DOS prompt: python; from pylab import *; figure(1); show() works.  If I start (windows-native) emacs with emacs -Q (turn off all customizations, so no elpy etc), then Alt-x run-python, I get a python (not ipython) prompt within emacs.  from pylab import *; figure(1); show() doesn't work - no figure window appears, and I don't get back a python prompt.

*** Original post:
Very annoying problem, have talked to elpy and matplotlib people but we are stumped.

Goal: run ipython as a process within emacs, and get matplotlib plots to work.  Regarding OSes, "linux is nice but I prefer emacs".

My setup: Windows 7, Python packages thru Anaconda (python 3.6.2, ipython 6.1.0, matplotlib 2.0.2), emacs - 25.3 official GNU windows build (NOT cygwin, though I use the cygwin tools like grep, diff, etc in emacs), elpy emacs package for working with python.

Elpy has support for ipython.  As long as I don't make a plot, this works fine - I can edit python files in emacs, send them to an ipython session, work in it.  Also, outside of emacs if I just run ipython from a DOS prompt, matplotlib figures work fine (also work fine from Spyder).

I have made sure to revert to a plain vanilla setup - no config files, TkAgg matplotlib backend (those Qt gave similar but slightly different problems).

So: I start ipython within emacs, and do 'pylab'.

** plt.ion(), figure(1):
window appears, with buttons on bottom.  ipython prompt works.  If I interact with the figure window, I get “not responding” in title, and MS Windows’ spinning shell.  If I close the figure window by clicking on the X in upper right, windows says “app not responding.”  Dialog box w/ End Process or Cancel.  End process kills figure and ipython session.

** If instead plt.ioff(), figure(1):
plot(1,1)
show()
I get a figure window with a plot, but if I interact with it I get “not responding.”  ipython prompt seems fine.  I can close window from prompt close(1) and ipython fine.

Tom Caswell (matplotlib) thinks it's an issue with the input hook.  I don't know how to work with this, but maybe it's enough of a clue.

I'd think the 'Venn diagram' for people using python for science + emacs + Windows wouldn't be that small.

Comment: same issue here with windows, though i can interactive with the figure when plt.ioff()

Answer (score 0):

The following has worked for several months: use jupyter console instead of ipython.  Jupyter ends up just running ipython, but something about the way it starts ipython or interfaces with Windows or emacs makes matplotlib work.  I don't quite understand why.  It's given me good results though.

I also stopped using elpy.  My .emacs has the following:

```
(setq python-shell-interpreter "jupyter"
  python-shell-interpreter-args "console --simple-prompt")
(setq python-shell-completion-native-enable nil)
```

The last line is probably not relevant to matplotlib figures.